# One-to-many join on composite primary key in jpa

Tags: java, entity-framework, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have search whole day but couldn't find the solution.

I have 2 entities `Table A` and `Table B`. `Table A` has 1 primary key and `Table B` has composite key. There is `oneToMany` mapping between `Table A and Table B`

I have created `Table A` Like below

```
@Entity
public class TableA {

@Id
private Integer sId;
private Integer roleNo;
private String studentName;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="roleNo")
private List<TableB> tableb;
}
```

Table B looks like below

```
@Entity
public class TableB {

@EmbededId
private CKStudent student;
private String activities;
}
```

here is my composite class

```
@Embeddable
public class CKStudent {

private Integer roleNo;
private Integer ActivityId;

}
```

I want to create query like this

```
select * 
from tableA a 
left join tableB on a.roleNo = b.roleNo 
where a.sId = 1 and b.activityId = 3
```

I have written jpa method for it

```
List<TableA> findBySIdAndtablebStudentActivityId(Integer id,Integer activityId);
```

but I am not getting the required result,

I am getting result for all the activityId, and not the activityId which I am passing through parameter.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

This JPA is creating 2 queries

Query #1

```
select 
    tbla0_.sId as s_id1_8_, tbla0_.roleNo as rol2_8_, 
    tbla0_.studentName as student_name3_8 
from tableA tbla0_ 
left outer join tableB tbl1_ on tbla0_.role_id = tbl1_.role_id 
where tbla0_.sId = ? 
  and tbl1_.activityId = ?
```

which is the correct query

Query #2

```
select 
    tblB1_.roleNo as roleNo_21_0_, tblB1_.activityId as activityId2_21_0_, 
    tblB1_.activities as act1_21_1_, 
from tableB tblB1_ 
where tblB1_.roleNo = ?
```

which is wrong and returning wrong results.

Comment: You don't need mappin table for one to many relationship.  Are you sure you don't want many to many e.g. 1 activity could be done by multiple students and 1 student can do multiple activities.

Comment: Yes in my case I need one to many relation

Comment: Can you provide the query, that hibernate generates for this method? (https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot)